# How to compare String that are closest in similarity - in Java

Tags: java

Is there a library in Java - that can do a spell check.

I have a ArrayList of Categories - which is a list of Words {Fox,Lion,Wolf,Snake}.  This list can be very big.

The program will ask the user to input the "Animal":   If the user makes a spelling mistake e.g. inserts "Fix" or "Loin"..

Is there a way to compare the input to the elements of the List and find the closest in similarity and use the corresponding element instead of the misspelled input for the rest of the program.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between two strings. The distance grows the more dissimilar the strings are.

Apache commons has an implementation: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/similarity/LevenshteinDistance.html

Comment: Thanks.  This should work.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a list of animals, then you could write your own code to check if the word is part of the list, it's length, amount of matching characters etc..